# CString to C without const

Tags: rust

I want call this C method from Rust:

```
int gb2312ToUtf8(char* ptDestText, int nDestLength, char* ptSrcText, int nSrcLength);
```

In Rust:

```
#[link(name = "testunicode")]
extern {
    fn gb2312ToUtf8(ptDestText: *char, nDestLength: int, ptSrcText: *char, nSrcLength: int) -> int;
}

pub fn test() {
    let srcText = CString::new("Hello, world!").expect("CString::new failed");
    let destText = CString::new("").expect("CString::new failed");
    let x = unsafe {
        gb2312ToUtf8(destText.as_ptr(), c_to_print.len(), srcText.as_bytes().as_ptr(), srcText.len());
    println!("test: {}", destText);
};
```

But I get this error:

```
error: expected mut or const in raw pointer type
  --> src\libc\libctest.rs:14:32
   |
14 |  fn gb2312ToUtf8( ptDestText : *char,nDestLength:int,ptSrcText: *char,  nSrcLength:int) -> int;
   |                                ^ expected mut or const in raw pointer type
   |
   = help: use `*mut T` or `*const T` as appropriate

error: expected mut or const in raw pointer type
  --> src\libc\libctest.rs:14:65
   |
14 |  fn gb2312ToUtf8( ptDestText : *char,nDestLength:int,ptSrcText: *char,  nSrcLength:int) -> int;
   |                                                                 ^ expected mut or const in raw pointer type
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Rust, raw pointers **always** need a mutability modifier. In this case you need to use `*mut c_char` type as this will be equivalent to C's `char *` type.